# Excluding specific sheets from script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a google script that sends out email alerts based on a specific due date. The script only does this on specified sheets, however, I'm looking to switch it so it *excludes* specific sheets instead (ie. "Template", "Tracker", "ExampleSheet"). As I'm not quite savvy when it comes to coding, I'm looking for some help on how to do this.

My current code below indicating which sheets to look at:

```
function feedbackAlert() {
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shts = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3'];
  const sr = 14;
  const numRows = 100;
  shts.forEach(name => {
    var arr = [];
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName(name);
    var vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, numRows, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var pn = sh.getRange("C5").getValue();
    vs.forEach((r, u) => {
      let ddt = new Date(r[5]);
      let ddtv = new Date(ddt.getFullYear(), ddt.getMonth(), ddt.getDate()).valueOf()
      let ddtF = Utilities.formatDate(ddt, 'ET', 'MM/dd/yyyy');
      let message = 
      `Feeback is due: ${pn} 
      Name: ${r[1]} 
      Formula #: ${r[2]} 
      Feedback due date: ${ddtF}
      \n`
      if (ddtv == dtv) {
        arr.push(message);
      }
    });
    if (arr && arr.length > 0) {
      MailApp.sendEmail('[EMAIL]', `Feedback is Due: ${pn}` , arr.join("\n"))
      Logger.log('NPD Feedback Alert!');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If every else is working you can replace everything down to just before the second forEach with this:

```
function feedbackAlert() {
  const dt = new Date();
  const dtv = new Date(dt.getFullYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate()).valueOf();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const excl = ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3'];//excluded sheets
  const shts = ss.getSheets().filter(sh => !~excl.indexOf(sh.getName())).filter(e => e)
  const sr = 14;
  const numRows = 100;
  shts.forEach(sh => {
    var arr = [];
    var vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, numRows, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var pn = sh.getRange("C5").getValue();
```